# How to run Chromedriver with the right Chrome version from JupyterLab?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am following this tutorial on how to create a python bot for auto-gpu-purchases: https://youtu.be/0jY4v4NDfcE

Unfortunately I am stuck at minute 05:41 and I can't reach further because I keep getting this error:

```
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-f0c0b1e14ca2> in <module>
----> 1 wd = wd.Chrome()
      2 wd.implicitly_wait(10)

~\anaconda3\envs\gpu_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     74 
     75         try:
---> 76             RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
     77                 self,
     78                 command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(

~\anaconda3\envs\gpu_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~\anaconda3\envs\gpu_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~\anaconda3\envs\gpu_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\envs\gpu_bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
Current browser version is 92.0.4515.131 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

As you can see from the video, this guy seems to have solved the problem by allowing the python script: the problem is that I am not getting any security notification as he does!

Apparently (as you can read at the bottom of the error message) the error is due to the fact that my Chromedriver version cannot run the 92 version of the Google Chrome browser that I have installed.
The only Chrome version running at 93 is the Beta one, which has a completely different binary path from the 92 one.

I tried to manually rename the two binary paths so that Chromedriver would have been forced to read only the Chrome Beta version: unfortunately, doing so, my JupyterLab app couldn't launch from the Anaconda Navigator so I am obliged to use the 92 version of Chrome browser, keeping the respective default binary paths names.

I also tried to install the webdriver_manager lib using the "conda install" from the Command Prompt as I saw other users getting over this problem in this way. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for me, maybe because I am working with the JupyterLab app and all the libs (Selenium, Chromedriver_binary, Beautiful Soup, Pandas, Webdrivermanager) are installed in an Anaconda environment I've set up (called "gpu_bot").

What should I try in order to solve this problem?